# jQuery datatables: manipulating full_numbers

Tags: jquery, datatables

Using

`"sPaginationType": "full_numbers"`

Shows

```
First,Prev, 1,2,3,4,5, Next, Last
```

I don't want to show 5 pages, I want to show only 3 like

```
First, Prev, 1, 2, 3, Next, Last
```

And then if user is on 3rd page then show

```
First, Prev, 3, 4, 5, Next, Last
```

How can this be done? I'm sure there should be an option in dataTables for that, I was unable to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only fix you can do by modifying the BootStrap Pagination plugin, found here
https://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination
add this:

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oPagination.iFullNumbersShowPage=3;
```

more details here:http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/20541/limit-number-of-page-tabs-with-bootstrap-pagination

or do this:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oPagination.iFullNumbersShowPages = 3; 
$('#my-table').dataTable({ //your options });
```

Comment: Thanks. Isn't there any other way to achieve this without modifying the dataTables.js file?

Comment: I got it. You have to do the below

`$.fn.dataTableExt.oPagination.iFullNumbersShowPages = 3;
$('#my-table').dataTable({
//your options
});` Thanks for leading in the right direction.